Doubt about guess validation for 2nd order non-homogeneous ODE
I am reading a section of a paper (Werning, 2012) where the author proves that the solution of a particular ODE takes a specific form.
Extract from the paper (with minor edits)
Consider a 2nd order non-homogeneous ODE of the form:
\begin{equation}
    \alpha_1 \mu(t) + \alpha_2 \dot{\mu}(t) + \ddot{\mu}(t) = a(t)
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $\mu(t_1) = \dot{\mu}(t_1) = 0$. To solve this equation postulate that:
\begin{equation}
    -r_1 \mu(t) + \dot{\mu}(t) = e^{r_2 t} \int_{t_1}^t e^{-r_2 s} a(s) ds
\end{equation}
for some constants $r_1$ and $r_2$, that will turn out to be the roots of the characteristic equation. This guess works because it implies, by differentiating both sides,
\begin{align}
    -r_1 \dot{\mu}(t) + \ddot{\mu}(t) &= r_2 e^{r_2 t} \int_{t_1}^t e^{-r_2 s} a(s) ds + a(t) = r_2 (-r_1 \mu(t) + \dot{\mu}(t)) + a(t) \\
&\Rightarrow r_1 r_2 \mu(t) - (r_1 + r_2) \dot{\mu}(t) + \ddot{\mu}(t) = a(t)
\end{align}
Matching coefficients gives
\begin{align}
    r_1 + r_2 = -\alpha_2 \quad r_1 r_2 = \alpha_1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \Rightarrow r_1 + \frac{\alpha_1}{r_1} + \alpha_2 = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1 + r_1 \alpha_2 + r_1^2 = 0
\end{align}
which is just the characteristic equation.
Question
I understand that the characteristic equation allows me to write the general solution to the homogeneous counterpart, but why does showing that $r_1$ satisfies the characteristic equation validate the fact that the guess is valid? Or am I misinterpreting what the author means?
